# Lvalue required when increment array ybase address using ++ operator

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

ERROR: lvalue required as increment operand.Increment base address of the array will through error.aiData = aiData+1; while will increment base address +1 right ? but it through error.

If I wrote aiData+1 it increments fine. Can't I use the `++` operator on Arrays?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    int aiData[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int *p=NULL;

    aiData++;
    printf("%d\n",P);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to increment aiData(aiData  = aiData + 1) which is wrong. You have to assign this array into another pointer and you are free to update your pointer

Comment: Yes , I am agreed with you. I am doing aiData = aiData +1. Suppose aiData have base address 0x1000. aiData = 0x1000 +1, why it can't ? Pointer had that capability, we already know this.

Comment: aiData is created in stack and now system is promised to delete all the variables created in the stack, if you try to modify aiData and move the base address system cannot delete the first element and that's against the promise.